# What is the meaning of the parameter d in the model $ a_{n+1}=a_{n}-ka_{n}+d $?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems, biology

In the following model I am having difficulty understanding the meaning of the parameter d in the context. I think it is a constant it terms of the dimension but I am not sure what it represents.

Any help would be really appreciated!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$d$ is the amount which is administered at discrete time intervals. The formula breaks up as follows:
$$
\text{drug in blood}_{n+1}=\text{drug in blood}_n-\text{drug metabolised}_n+\text{drug administered}
$$
One usually assumes that drug metabolism rate, at least for small doses, is proportional to the concentration / amount of the drug in the bloodstream. This proportion is what $k$ signifies.

Comment: If d is the amount of drug administered at 'discrete time intervals' should it not also have a subscript n?

Comment: @chloeloughan Only if we administer different amounts at different times. If the administered amount is the same each time there is no need to make it a sequence.